# IIS 6.0 Gzip Compression in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I am not good at IIS management.I enabled gzip compression for my web site but In IIS Temporary Compressed Files folder,i dont see any aspx type file.I just see js,text,css and some html files.Is that normal?Why dont i see aspx pages as compressed.Thats my metabase.xml and i think that my settings are true.

IIsCompressionScheme Location ="/LM/W3SVC/Filters/Compression/deflate"
  HcCompressionDll="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"
  HcCreateFlags="0"
  HcDoDynamicCompression="TRUE"
  HcDoOnDemandCompression="TRUE"
  HcDoStaticCompression="TRUE"
  HcDynamicCompressionLevel="10"
  HcFileExtensions="htm
   html
   xml
   css
   txt
   rdf
   js"
  HcOnDemandCompLevel="10"
  HcPriority="1"
  HcScriptFileExtensions="asp
   cgi
   exe
   dll
   aspx
   asmx"
 >
/IIsCompressionScheme>

IIsCompressionScheme Location ="/LM/W3SVC/Filters/Compression/gzip"
  HcCompressionDll="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"
  HcCreateFlags="1"
  HcDoDynamicCompression="TRUE"
  HcDoOnDemandCompression="TRUE"
  HcDoStaticCompression="TRUE"
  HcDynamicCompressionLevel="10"
  HcFileExtensions="htm
   html
   xml
   css
   txt
   rdf
   js"
  HcOnDemandCompLevel="10"
  HcPriority="1"
  HcScriptFileExtensions="asp
   cgi
   exe
   dll
   aspx
   asmx"
 >
/IIsCompressionScheme>

IIsCompressionSchemes Location ="/LM/W3SVC/Filters/Compression/Parameters"
  HcCacheControlHeader="max-age=86400"
  HcCompressionBufferSize="8192"
  HcCompressionDirectory="%windir%\IIS Temporary Compressed Files"
  HcDoDiskSpaceLimiting="FALSE"
  HcDoDynamicCompression="TRUE"
  HcDoOnDemandCompression="TRUE"
  HcDoStaticCompression="TRUE"
  HcExpiresHeader="Wed, 01 Jan 1997 12:00:00 GMT"
  HcFilesDeletedPerDiskFree="256"
  HcIoBufferSize="8192"
  HcMaxDiskSpaceUsage="99614720"
  HcMaxQueueLength="1000"
  HcMinFileSizeForComp="1"
  HcNoCompressionForHttp10="FALSE"
  HcNoCompressionForProxies="FALSE"
  HcNoCompressionForRange="FALSE"
  HcSendCacheHeaders="FALSE"
 >
/IIsCompressionSchemes>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out MCB... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/http-compression-and-iis-6-0.html

This is another article for troubleshooting HTTP Compression.
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/webtopics/troubleshooting-http-compression-in-iis-6-0)

I hope this helps.

Editing as per my comment
[image]

Comment: unfortunately i did these settings,nothing changed.I want to learn that compressed aspx pages is stored in IIS Temporary Compressed Files or not?

Comment: Ohh, I see what you are saying. IIS Temporary Compressed files folder is meant only for Static files. You won't see dynamic files getting compressed over there.

Comment: What you need to do is install a tool like Fiddler, www.fiddlertool.com. Once you have Fiddler running, access the page again, and see if the response is encoded or not. Editing my main reply so that you could see how it would look like in a screenshot.

If it helps, please mark as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The settings seem to be ok. I've done this a lot in the past with good success. How are you checking if it is working or not?

Follow the guide at http://alexkuo.info/archive/2009/10/28/55.aspx for how to do this, or edit metabase.xml directly (after you enable editing of it).

Comment: I am checking by  looking IIS Temporary Compressed Files folder and i dont see any aspx page.Therefore i think that it doesnt compress aspx pages.

Comment: Have you tried to check with your browser as well? For example sniff the packets with Fiddler to see if they arrive gzip'ed.